# Problem with fsharpi on Mac OS X: Failed to install ctrl-c handler - Ctrl-C handling will not be available

Tags: macos, f#, mono

I have installed mono 2.8.1 using the package installer from mono-project.com and the f sharp libs/bins from http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/releases/view/55463.

When I run fsharpi from the Terminal, I get the following back:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build
2.0.0.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

Failed to install ctrl-c handler - Ctrl-C handling will not be available. Error was:  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Sad times, I have tried running mono --verbose /usr/lib/fsharp/fsi.exe but I can't see anything helpful in the logs....

```
Method System.MulticastDelegate:Equals (object) emitted at 0x4714c78 to 0x4714d0a (code length 146) [fsi.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib:sys_signal (int,Mono.Unix.Native.SignalHandler)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib:sys_signal (int,Mono.Unix.Native.SignalHandler) emitted at 0x4714d10 to 0x4714d89 (code length 121) [fsi.exe]
converting method System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:.ctor (System.Exception)
Method System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:.ctor (System.Exception) emitted at 0x4714d90 to 0x4714dae (code length 30) [fsi.exe]
converting method System.ApplicationException:.ctor (string,System.Exception)
Method System.ApplicationException:.ctor (string,System.Exception) emitted at 0x4714dc0 to 0x4714de6 (code length 38) [fsi.exe]
converting method System.Exception:.ctor (string,System.Exception)
Method System.Exception:.ctor (string,System.Exception) emitted at 0x4714df8 to 0x4714e16 (code length 30) [fsi.exe]
converting method System.Exception:get_Message ()
Method System.Exception:get_Message () emitted at 0x4714e18 to 0x4714e52 (code length 58) [fsi.exe]
converting method FSIstrings.SR:fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler (string)
Method FSIstrings.SR:fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler (string) emitted at 0x4714e60 to 0x4714ed8 (code length 120) [fsi.exe]
converting method <StartupCode$Fsi>.$FSIstrings/fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler@222:Invoke (System.Tuple`2<string, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, string>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, string, string, string>>)
Method <StartupCode$Fsi>.$FSIstrings/fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler@222:Invoke (System.Tuple`2<string, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<string, string>, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, string, string, string>>) emitted at 0x4714ed8 to 0x4714f14 (code length 60) [fsi.exe]
converting method <StartupCode$Fsi>.$FSIstrings/fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler@222-1:Invoke (string)
Method <StartupCode$Fsi>.$FSIstrings/fsiCouldNotInstallCtrlCHandler@222-1:Invoke (string) emitted at 0x4714f18 to 0x4714f35 (code length 29) [fsi.exe]
converting method System.IO.UnexceptionalStreamWriter:Write (char)
Method System.IO.UnexceptionalStreamWriter:Write (char) emitted at 0x4714f38 to 0x4714f74 (code length 60) [fsi.exe]
Failed to install ctrl-c handler - Ctrl-C handling will not be available. Error was:
 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I have also tried running with all permutations of --readline- --nologo --gui- with no success :(

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  What is more infuriating is that this seems to only be affecting me, as a friend of mine installed it fine using the exact same install method.  Could MacPorts be affecting my fsharp install?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers

Jan

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256918/fsi-exe-does-not-work-under-ubuntu-10-10 - do you have Apple's X installed?

Comment: It's possible, MacPorts is known to cause problems for Mono because it overrides system tools and libraries. Try in an environment without MacPorts.

Comment: Actually I'm having the same problem and it persists even when not using Macports.
Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you should go to this,

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

which is the F# for Mono.

The CodePlex one has significant dependency on Windows.

Comment: Your link to the community-maintained source branch is useful, but the CodePlex project that the asker linked is for community-maintained cross-platform packages. Also, I believe the MS version is tested against Mono - the stack trace looks like a Unix-specific codepath.