# Mono, F# libraries not working under Mac OSX

Tags: macos, f#, mono, f#-interactive

I have a very simple question. I tried to google it, but to no avail.

I installed Mono and F# with Macports in OSX. There are some bugs in F# interactive, but still it's usable if you call it from emacs with F# mode.

Now, the problem is that although F# is there and works, even the simplest of libraries/functions are not available.
For instance, the following code doesn't run, with the error that it can't find, neither **sum**, neither **out**:

```
let sumMultiples n =
    [1..n]
    |> List.filter (fun i -> (i%3 = 0 || i%5 = 0))
    |> List.sum

let out = sumMultiples 999

printfn "%d" out
```

And the error given is:

```
test.fs(6,12): error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'sum' is not defined.


test.fs(10,17): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'out' is not defined.
stopped due to error
```

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: Which versions of Mono and F# are they? Your functions seem to have incorrect indentation in last two lines.

Comment: @pad: Hi, thanks for the repair, I've corrected the indentation.
Mono version 2.10.6. F# version 1.9.4.19.

Comment: F# 1.9.4.19 is quite old. BTW, there is a newer version of F# included in Mono 2.10.6 (You could check it by typing `fsc` or `fsi` in the terminal). Could you check if your code works in the newer version of F#?

Comment: @pad: Well, I removed MacPorts f# and mono and installed a package from the mono site for the mono distribution and the f#. It now works as expected. But I still get the error: `Failed to install ctrl-c handler - Ctrl-C handling will not be available. Error was:
        Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`. Still, it looks like something is wrong with the f# package of MacPorts.

Comment: Well, at least it solves your problem :). You should get rid of F# package of MacPorts completely because it will be always obsolete compared to F# package in Mono itself. My advice is that you should always try to install the latest version of Mono and F#. Since F# Mono is quite unstable, there's a lot of improvement in each release.

Comment: When did you get the above error? Did you invoke Ctrl-C inside Emacs in F# mode or press Ctrl-C in fsi in the terminal?

Comment: @pad: I get the error whenever I start fsi, either from emacs or from the command line. I don't need to press Ctrl-C for it to appear.
There are 2 problems to that: 1-I cannot get out of fsi, 2-That message shows up every time I use fsi and garbles the output of what I'm trying to test. But well, at least the libraries work now. And I'll do what you say. My idea is to use Mono from MacPorts, since is very up to date and compile F# from the git development source. I'll see if they work well together this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some instructions I recently wrote up for getting F# working under Mono (on Mac)
https://github.com/Phrogz/laink/wiki/F%23s-on-Mac

You code works after following those steps:

```
~/code/fs harold$ cat test.fs
let sumMultiples n =
    [1..n]
    |> List.filter (fun i -> (i%3 = 0 || i%5 = 0))
    |> List.sum

let out = sumMultiples 999

printfn "%d" out

~/code/fs harold$ fsc test.fs
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

~/code/fs harold$ mono test.exe
233168
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the summary of discussion with @jbssm through comments:

- The original configuration is Mono 2.10.6 and F# 1.9.4.19 (an old F#
  version dated back to 2008) installed through MacPorts. His attempt
  to remove those packages and install Mono from disk image gets the
  test code work, but results in a weird error `Failed to install
  ctrl-c handler - Ctrl-C handling will not be available. Error was:
  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` whenever
  starting fsi.

And lets start my answer from here:

1. To get out of fsi without Ctrl-C, I think you always can use
   `#quit;;`. **To solve the new problem, you may find the answer of [the
   following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256918/fsi-exe-does-not-work-under-ubuntu-10-10) helpful.**
2. I find it a little bit weird because your new F# configuration
   should work. **Have you installed new Mono and F# using or not using MacPorts because it's a [known bug](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32120) of F# on MacPorts?** If you're not using MacPorts, my guess is there are some data left from the old Mono
   installation on MacPorts which conflicts with the new Mono
   installation. If the first suggestion doesn't work, maybe you should
   follow the below procedure:

   1. [Remove old Mono installation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX#Uninstalling_Mono_on_Mac_OS_X).
   2. [Install latest Mono version from disk image](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html): Mono 2.10 onwards includes F# package already so no need to install a separate
      F# package.
   3. Try your test script with `fsi` on the terminal.
   4. Update Emacs configuration (if needed) and try to run F# on Emacs.

   I have Mono 2.10 with F# running on my Mac (though I don't use
   Emacs), so I don't think there's any problem installing Mono 2.10
   from scratch.

Please give follow-up information, if any of them works for you.

Comment: Very interesting that Mono now includes F#. Thanks for pointing that out.